# Migration from AlchemyNews to Watson Discovery gives 401 error in Swift V3 com.ibm.watson.developer-cloud.DiscoveryV1 Code=401

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

Hello I have moved over from AlchemyAPI to DiscoveryV1 but my swift program is getting a 401 error, rror Domain=com.ibm.watson.developer-cloud.DiscoveryV1 Code=401 "Not Authorized" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Not Authorized}

The app was working fine before moving to Discovery and the Bluemix support team have verified the credentials and get no error when running the query in BLuemix

for the sake of it I also added the url into the App transport Security settings which was a guess but it didn't change the error I have added a a screen capture of the App Transport settings

here are the credentials I am using
    let wdn = Discovery(username: "my-user-name",
    password: "my-password",
    version: "2017-03-08")

```
let environmentID = "envID generated under my account on bluemix"
let collectionID = "collectionID generated under my account on bluemix"
let filter = ""
let query = newsSearchString < variable set later
let aggregation = "term(enriched_text.concepts.text).top_hits(10)"
let numberOfItemsToReturn = 30
let failure = { (error: Error) in print(error) }
let returnEntities = "enriched.url.url,enriched.url.title,enriched.url.author"




[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UvJO.png
```

Comment: Note that I used the SDK at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk?cm_mc_uid=85560740713514864449553&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1488950751#discovery.    I used the  environmentID and collectionID generated on Bluemix, and then just used the query against those IDs, I did not create the collection and environment IDs in the application

Comment: I used this App Transport Security Settings <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>watsonplatform.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

Comment: Which are from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk?cm_mc_uid=85560740713514864449553&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1488950751#discovery

Comment: I upgraded to the latest iOS-sdk and got an additional mesage

Comment: Error Domain=com.ibm.watson.developer-cloud.DiscoveryV1 Code=401 "Not Authorized" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Not Authorized, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=No credentials supplied.}

Comment: Note that the app transport security specifies watsonplatform.net but the error is coming from com.ibm.watson.developer-cloud.DiscoveryV1 Code=401

Comment: I also created a new bare bones app from scratch and followed all the steps at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk?cm_mc_uid=85560740713514864449553&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1488950751#watson-developer-cloud-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new app + service, and did not get an unauthorized error. Here are the steps I followed:

[image: code]
[image: app transport security settings]

1. I downloaded the [Watson Conversation starter from Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/mobile/create-project/). This includes a lightweight Watson project which includes the SDKs and settings necessary to get set up quickly (essentially all you have to do is put your credentials in a config file for the Converation service).
2. Because that starter has all of the Watson configuration set up, I just imported the `DiscoveryV1` service, dragged the Framework over to my project (updated the Build Phase), and typed in the initialization snippet and everything is working for me.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have used quite a few Watson Bluemix services and all work OK and I just made a couple of changes to switch from Alchemy to DiscoveryV1. One thing I did that could be the issue is that I used the credentials of the service as well as the environmentID & collectionID that were generated in Bluemix when I created the service and did not generate them in my program.

Comment: I went to my Discovery service on Bluemix, then selected the "Launch tool", then selected the "PRE_ENRICHED DATA - WATSON NEWS" . The heading "Collections of your private data and pre-enriched data to configure and query against.Learn more." led me to believe I could just use these credentials and IDs and run the query without having to create the environment from my program

Comment: Joe: Did you run a queryDocumentsInCollection or some other method, most other methods work but not this one? I "think" there is a problem the way the SDK is handling the authorisations against the "Watson News" public collection. I have done as you suggested with the starters etc but same problem when I try the queryDocumentsInCollection

Comment: Well, thought thought wrong.. problem was with my Framework. I had used the carthage update --platform iOS but something wasn't correct with the Framework as a colleague supplied his Framework and it all worked.

Comment: Problem appears to be related to building the framework in an external directory and copying into the application directory. I resolved the problem by building the Carthage iOS SDK frameworks inside the program directory. Now that has been done I can delete the Carthage directory in the program directory after I copied the frameworks to the root application directory

Comment: Hi @jeff, if this helped answer your question, could you mark this answer as correct? It helps others who have the same question find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: So Sorry Joe, new to stackoverflow and wasn't aware of that ...done now....I assume selecting the tick is what is done on here